# sending multiple forms with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My page creates a form for every entry on my database, I have set it up to save the value on pressing enter, my question is: How do distinguish between the forms and make them send the right data to the database? My code only lets me save one particular form, is there a way to make it handle the right form?

PHP:

```
echo '<td><form action="update_result.php" method="POST">
<span id="result-text-'.$row['id'].'" ondblclick="changeToInput('.$row['id'].')">kein Ergebnis</span>
<input type="hidden" id="runner_id-'.$row['id'].'" name="runner_id" value="'.$row['id'].'">
<input id="result-'.$row['id'].'" type="text" name="result" style="display:none"><button type="submit" hidden>Save</button></form>';
```

Javascript:

```
function changeToInput(x) {
    document.getElementById('result-text-'+x).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('result-'+x).style.display = 'block';
  }

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (event) {
    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    $(".help-block").remove();
    var formData = {
      runner_id: $("#runner_id"+x).val(),
      result: $("#result"+x).val(),
    };
    console.log(x);

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "update_result.php",
      data: formData,
      dataType: "json",
      encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        $("form").html(
          '<div class="alert alert-danger">Could not reach server, please try again later.</div>'
        );
      });

    if (!data.success) {
        if (data.errors.runner_id) {
          $("#runner_id-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#runner_id-group").append(
            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.runner_id + "</div>"
          );
        }

        if (data.errors.result) {
          $("#result-group").addClass("has-error");
          $("#result-group").append(
            '<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.result + "</div>"
          );
        }

      } else {
        $("form").html(
          '<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + "</div>"
        );
      }

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: you can use a selector for all the forms (`form`) and within the event handler you can refer to that specific form using `this` or `event,target`

Comment: You're not setting `x` in the `.submit()` function. Instead of using ID selectors, use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)`

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs. Then you can do `$(this).find(".runner-id").val()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `event.target` property in your form submission callback to make sure you're saving the appropriate form.

[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will be the HTMLFormElement that was submitted. Afterwards, you can grab the values from that form by instantiating a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object with from form like so:

```js
$("form").submit(function (event) {
  // Get FormData of submitted form
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  // Extract input values, validate if needed
  const data = {
    runner_id: formData.get('runner_id'), // Refers to the 'name' property of the input
    result: formData.get('result'),
  };

  // AJAX, result handling...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I incorporated your suggestion and it works for all the forms, but the first one does not work anymore. Do you have any idea why this may be?